# coreutils date does not return time zone when called from script

Tags: date, timezone, coreutils

In terminal, the output of the lines

```
TZ="Australia/Broken_Hill" date -d '2021-4-26 09:29'
TZ="Australia/Broken_Hill" date -d '2021-4-26 09:29' +%Z
```

is

```
Mon Apr 26 09:29:00 AM ACST 2021
ACST
```

If, in contrast, I run `./script.sh` with the lines

```
date_in="2021-4-26 09:29"
tz_in="Australia/Broken_Hill"
date_out=$(TZ=\"$tz_in\" date -d "$date_in")
tz_out=$(TZ=\"$tz_in\" date -d "$date_in" +%Z)
echo $date_out
echo $tz_out
```

the output is

```
Mon Apr 26 09:29:00 AM 2021
# empty line
```

Why is the time zone omitted when called from script?

Thanks!
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you quote the quote characters? You must change `\"` to `"`:

```
date_in="2021-4-26 09:29"
tz_in="Australia/Broken_Hill"
date_out=$(TZ="$tz_in" date -d "$date_in")
tz_out=$(TZ="$tz_in" date -d "$date_in" +%Z)
echo $date_out
echo $tz_out
```

Answer (score 0):

I confused the escaping since it is needed for

```
date_in="2021-4-26 09:29"
tz_in="Australia/Broken_Hill"
time=$(date -d "TZ=\"$tz_in\" $date_in")
echo $time
```

Comment: Notice that `TZ="$tz_in" date -d "$date_in"` as fixed from your question is different to `date -d "TZ=\"$tz_in\" $date_in"` in this answer. If `$tz_in` is your timezone then they will appear to be the same, but for any situation where it is a different timezone the values will be different